# Converting component state to JSON in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I am new to React JS. I wanted to convert the component state data into a JSON object. Is it possible? If so, how?

Sample state :

```html
this.state = {
    name : "Example",
    age : "21",
    description : "Some text here."
}
```

That's the whole question. I would appreciate it if you could tell me where I can find simple tutorials to do more advanced things in React (like sending/receiving JSON to/from a server, doing redirects, creating menus, etc). I know I sound vague, and I don't expect very specific answers(if any) to this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use `JSON.stringify` method in order to turn an `javascript` object into `JSON` **text** and store that `JSON` text in a **string**.

Also, you can use `JSON.parse` which turns a string of **JSON** text into a `Javascript` object.

```js
let state = {
    name : "Example",
    age : "21",
    description : "Some text here."
}
console.log(state);
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: Can I store JSX state value in JSON?